# How do I show all my Gmail on one page?

Tags: gmail

I use Yahoo mail and it shows all my mail on one page. How do I get my Gmail to do the same thing? I think it is more convenient that way.

Comment: Are you referring to the organisation of tabs/categories or the actual number of emails viewed on a single page?

Comment: Please clarify what @w3d is asking and the question can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Click the `Settings` button on the upper-right corner on Gmail, and a drop-down menu will appear. See the screenshot below

[image: The drop-down menu when click on the Settings button]

Select the `Configure inbox` option and you will see something like the following screenshot

[image: Configure inbox tab for Gmail]

Un-check the `Social`, `Promotions`, `Updates`, `Forums` and `Include starred in Primary` options.

Now the tabs will be removed and you will have only one tab to receive your emails.